# Cobertura Eclipse Plugin Local site - Download as Zip

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cobertura, ecobertura

I am trying to install the eCobertura plugin for Eclipse.  In doing so, I found the update site http://ecobertura.johoop.de/update/.

But it's not working for me, probably due to some firewall issues.  Is there a bundle I can download and install as a Local Site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be any package to let you install it manually. You can try these:

- Install it via the marketplace inside Eclipse. Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace, enter eCobertura in the search field and try to install it
- Go to the web marketplace : https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ecobertura and drag and drop the Install button to your Eclipse
- Last resort, build the sources from BitBucket : https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/jmhofer/ecobertura/ You will need a BitBucket account. Instructions to build it can be found there : http://ecobertura.johoop.de/contribute.html

Anyway, I think that sorting out your firewall issues is probably easier than the last one...